# How to know if another program is reading your memory?

Tags: security, memory

I'd like to know if you can detect that another application is reading the memory of your own program using [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx).

My question is related to the fact that Blizzard's games are protected by a "warden", that is able to detect cheats and bots injecting memory.

I get how they can check if the memory is injected, but can they also detect if it's only getting read by another program?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of detecting external hacks which may use ReadProcessMemory() an anticheat can scan all external processes using signatures and heuristics to detect if something could be a cheat.

In the context of internal hacks, they don't use ReadProcessMemory but are injected into the game process and can read or modify the memory directly. An anticheat can simply detect injection methods or any allocation of memory to detect an internal cheat.

An anticheat which is running as administrator can also get a list of all the open process handles and detect what processes have permissions to interact with the game process.  Code which can show you how that works is available [here](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827/Examine-Information-on-Windows-NT-System-Level-Primitives.htm)

A combination of these techniques only gives you an indicator of risk, further investigation is required to detect if the process is legitimate or not.